# Workaround ghc 7.6 lack of NegativeLiterals

Tags: haskell, ghc

My code relies on:

```
case x of
    (-32768) -> Nothing
    otherwise -> Just x
```

`x` is an `Int16` which has a range from -32768 to +32767.

Which works with the `NeativeLiterals` extension of GHC 7.8. I can't find GHC 7.8 for Redhat RHEL6 so I'm trying to get it working with GHC 7.6. The catch is that `NegativeLiterals` is new in 7.8.

Does anyone know a workaround?

Comment: This function works as written for me with ghc-7.6 using ghci.

Comment: Yeah. Sorry @JohnL. It works fine on 7.6 but on 7.8 it causes a warning about how you should use NegativeLiterals which is new in 7.8 so I did use NegativeLiterals and that's what won't compile on 7.6. I think the answer is to live with the warning on 7.8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use guards:

EDIT: Ok, so I need explicit typing. That should have been obvious.  So the revised solution is:

```
foo :: Int16 -> Maybe Int16
foo x =
  case x of
    y | y == fromIntegral (-32768) -> Nothing
      | otherwise                  -> Just x
```

Comment: You have to make `x` a <s>`Word16`</s> `Int16` to see the problem.

Comment: Yes, I have done that and tested using 7.4.2 and 7.6.3 without incident.  `f :: Word16 -> Maybe Word16` where the body of `f` is your original code.  Could you copy and paste your error message?

Comment: Um. Maybe never mind. I was getting a warning from 7.8 telling me to use NegativeLiterals which caused it to not build on 7.6. But taking out NegativeLiterals and it builds and works fine on 7.6 so I guess we're good. Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelFox Ok I see.  I hadn't been aware of this shortcoming before, huh.  You can still compare for equality but you need your literal via a round-about method such as using `fromIntegral`.